# Hibernate query for multiple classes with max results

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have two classes (One and Two) and two corresponding tables ("one" and "two"). Each table has a time column ("timeOne" and "timeTwo").

I would like to get the last 10 results from both of these tables in a single query. Basically, if I have 30 rows in table "one" and 3 of them have been added today and my table two has 30 rows and 7 of them have been added today, my query should return 10 rows (3 from one and 7 from two).

I would like to do this in a single Hibernate query if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be simplest to use a native query.

I say this because the alternative is that you use something in JPQL like this:

```
Query q = entityManager
                .createQuery("select f, b from Foo f, Bar b");

q.setMaxResults(2);
```

Which produces the following SQL:

```
select foo0_.id as id0_0_, bar1_.id as id1_1_, foo0_.val as val0_0_, bar1_.val as val1_1_ from dbo.Foo foo0_ cross join dbo.Bar bar1_ limit ?
```

(Note that I've omitted ordering for brevity, but you can `order by`)

I believe you will get (maxResults * maxResults) rows back from the cross join, and although you could then collapse that result set in to distinct entities... it's unlikely that it will be what you want (nor will it be as efficient as possible).

So, rather than trying to deal with the above mess, using a native query would be simplest (programatically) and most efficient.

**In short:** No, as far as I understand you cannot do what you want to do through JPA or Hibernate in a manner that produces type-safe results that are attached to the persistence unit.

Comment: I've tried this. First of all, I get an Object back, not a particular type. Secondly, if I need to query this from 10 different tables, I'm worried that it won't be efficient.

Comment: After some more thinking I don't think that your approach will work. There needs to be an order by.

Comment: Right. Let me clarify my answer, because I wasn't suggesting that you should do what I was showing you (although you can put "order by f.timeOne, b.timeTwo") -- it was meant to suggest you use a native query instead.

Comment: Thank you, Doug. Do you have any thoughts on what the actual query would be?